# Save to Google Drive button not working on Chrome

Tags: google-drive-api

The official demo page of the Save to Google Drive button doesn't seem to work on Chrome. It works ok on Firefox/Safari.

If you point your Chrome to go here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/savetodrive
then hit the Save button a popup appears but once you select the destination and hit Save in the popup, the window is closed but no feedback is then given on the button tooltip as it happens on other browsers (and the file is not saved either).

Any idea on what may be wrong there?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the problem. What version of Chrome are you using? Can you try an incognito window?

Comment: That looks fixed now! It wasn't working all last week. We can close this issue! Thank you